# Terraform add all resources from for_each to policy document

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

I have a resource created by using `for_each`:

```
module "compactor_sqs" {
  source = "..."
  for_each = var.enabled_providers
  ...
}
```

Single `module.compactor_sqs` has `.arn` property so previously I was able to do:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "generator_sqs_document" {
  statement {
    actions   = ["sqs:*"]
    resources = [module.compactor_sqs.arn]
  }
}
```

Now that the resource is created using `for_each` I tried to change policy to this:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "generator_sqs_document" {
  statement {
    actions   = ["sqs:*"]
    resources = [module.compactor_sqs[*].arn]
  }
}
```

But terraform doesn't like it. It tells me that:

```
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│ 
│   on lambda.tf line 66, in data "aws_iam_policy_document" "generator_sqs_document":
│   66:     resources = [module.compactor_sqs[*].arn]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.compactor_sqs is object with 2 attributes
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "resources": element 0: string required.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on lambda.tf line 66, in data "aws_iam_policy_document" "generator_sqs_document":
│   66:     resources = [module.compactor_sqs[*].arn]
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "arn".
```

How do I pass all resources' property to this?

Comment: Please do not post error as screenshots, but use properly formatted code blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have used `for_each`, to access `arn` you have to use `values`:

```
 resources = values(module.compactor_sqs)[*].arn
```